# LetsEncrypt and Intermediate Certificates

Tags: nginx, ssl, lets-encrypt

I'm starting to use LetsEncrypt certs instead of proprietary ones.  The hosting provider installs these for me, and they work great.

However, wondering about LC's intermediate certificates.  In my previous usage with GeoTrust (for example), they would supply the intermediate cert, and I had to place a line in my nginx.conf server block security parameters section:

```
# OCSP stapling
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    #trusted cert must be made up of your intermediate certificate followed by root certificate
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/authority_certs/ocsp-geotrust-chain.crt;
```

I'm not seeing that LC has a similar mechanism for intermediate certs being placed on my server.  However, their use is explained here:
https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/

Should I just grab the intermediate cert from LC, put on my server, and point to it?  Or something else?
Note that Qualys SSL Labs testing doesn't make mention of it.

Comment: Looks to be fairly well covered in the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html). Basically you put them all in that one file.